# Multi-bullet Doxygen @note?

Tags: comments, doxygen, idioms, multiple-entries

In non-Doxygen comments, I often have:

```
/* Lorem ipsum etc.
 *
 * Notes:
 * - A first note.
 * - Some other note note.
 */
```

But with Doxygen, I have `@note` (or `\note`), not `@notes`). So, should I use multiple `@note`s, or do I put all notes under the same `@note`?

Answer (score 4):

The @note command results in a paragraph which format can be customized in the CSS file or in the style file when using Latex. So you can just use the markups like in a "normal" text:

```
/**
 * Bla bla...
 *
 * @note Even in a note you can use markups:
 *       - Your first note
 *       - Youre second note
 *
 * The note section ends with an empty line or the end of the comment.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way; it's really a question of style/preference.

As you pointed out, Doxygen has the `@note` command, but not `@notes`. You can create your own command for `@notes` by editing the Doxyfile, and modifying the `ALIASES =` tag to read

```
ALIASES = "notes=@par Notes:\n"
```

With this, you can put the command `@notes` in the documentation, which will result in a user-defined paragraph with the heading

> **Notes:**

As pointed out in the [Doxygen documentation for the ALIAS tag](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases), you can put \n's in the value part of an alias to insert newlines.

Comment: Ok, although the build people are going to complain that I'm wasting my time and their with minutiae rather than doing actual work...

Comment: I don't have an answer for that one.